# Implementing bucket sort - better performance with calloc?

Tags: c

I'm trying to implement something using a Bucket Sort algorithm in C,
So for the algorithm to work, I need to manually initialize every item in the array to zero,
but I'f i'll use `calloc` instead, I'll get all the values initialized to zero anyway.

The only difference I know for sure is that by using `calloc` I'm putting it all in the heap memory - is that a big difference?

The question is - what are the pros and cons for either way? (performance, etc.)

Comment: not sure why do you want to initialize to zero.. it's not needed in bucket sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to allocate and zero fill an array, then calloc is the simplest way to do it. Don't let the zero initialize drive the choice between stack or heap allocation. Make that choice independently.

Don't get hung up on performance of the allocation and initialization. You are sorting. The sorting will dominate. You won't be able to reliably measure the allocation and zero initialization. As always with performance, if you really want to know, measure.